# PHP to put variables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, api

I want to put the variable of json into mysql. What should I do?

The json code was output by the API.

json view:

```
Array(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [bizesId] => 333333
                            [lon] => 00.000000
                            [lat] => 00.000000
                        )

                )

)
```

If you enter the code, you can see that "1" is output.

**PHP Code:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "
INSERT INTO TEST (
    num,
    lon,
    lat
) VALUES (
  '5',
  'ddd',
  'fff'
)");
```

But,

**PHP Code:**

```
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "
     INSERT INTO TEST (
         number,
         lon,
         lat
     ) VALUES (
         $html[body][items][$i][bizesid],
         $html[body][items][$i][lon],
         $html[body][items][$i][lat]
     )");
}

     if($result)
       echo "1";
     else
       echo "-1";
```

The result is "-1". What should I do?

Comment: it's because insersion not happening. Did you checked the table? data inserted or not?

Comment: `$html[body][items][$i][bizesid]` will not resolve to the actual value. Some error checking or parameter binding would help.

Comment: There is no particular reason for setting the value to 5. I set 5 as a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Your current code is wide-open for `SQL INJECTION`, so use `prepared statements`.

2.For current solution Use `foreach()` along with modification in query code as well as checking query executed or not?

```
foreach($html['body']['items'] as $arr){
    if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO TEST (`number`,`lon`,`lat`) VALUES ('". $arr['bizesid'] ."','". $arr['lon'] ."','". $arr['lat'] ."')")){
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
```

***Important Note:-*** Use ***`prepared statements`*** to prevent yourself from ***SQL INJECTION***

[mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Do not use the code in this answer in production, always use prepared statements.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  i have added a proper note along with helpful links too.

Answer (score 0):

Values in insert query must be in single quotes. Also key in array should also be in single quote.

```
INSERT INTO TEST (
     number,
     lon,
     lat
 ) VALUES (
     '".$html['body']['items'][$i]['bizesid']."',
     '".$html['body']['items'][$i]['lon']."',
     '".$html['body']['items'][$i]['lat']."'
 )");
```

Comment: Entering 'html' will cause an error. If you change 'html' to 'result_json', "-1" is output.